# How many rows in a sql server should we retrieve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

Right now, I need a query to send mail to all the registered users for some task. For this I need their userdetails and some data about which I will mail them.

My question is **do I use join and retrieve all the data** from sql-server and structure them in NodeJS and send mail, or **do i retrieve first the data that needs to be mailed today and then for each post I retrieve the relevant people** to mail too and then send mail?

PS: The server is across network

Comment: So you are asking about retrieving the data in one sql query vs many?

Comment: yes. considering that data is not on same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining the tables is clearly more efficient and easier, since you need only one query.

If you first get the data, how can you find the corresponding people later? Querying each person one by one will create a lot of queries. You can try to optimize the query with the use of an IN-clause looking like `WHERE person_id IN (45,77,12,23,124, ...)` but creating this list is tedious and the length of IN-clauses is limited, so you would have to split the list and combine them with OR, or create several queries. Why do this manually, if the JOIN does it for you?

Each roundtrip to the server is time consuming. On the other hand, the db-server can handle joins in a very optimized way.

Comment: And what about retrieving 50000 rows in that case. Will it be a problem? Like my nodejs server crash or My hosting company ban me etc.

Comment: No, some people are retrieving millions of rows. Sendig all these e-mails will be the much bigger problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Will there be a problem in sending these many mails? May you recommend me best practice( any post, article etc)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've never sent such big numbers of e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on data.

If you are using same post/content for all users then 1st approach is good.

But scenarios can turns complex as your system grows. Think about tomorrow, you might need scheduler which will read user details, their preferences may be mail digest for a week / daily mail etc, categories for post etc. In such case, 2nd option is good.

Possibly you are not going to send 1 million mails in a one shot. You can use scheduler which will runs after per-determined time and sends mail. May be another scheduler will invoke failed jobs only etc.